# Windows Store app only crashes when installed from Windows Store in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

My Windows 8.1 app only crashes when it's installed from the Windows Store on Windows 8.1. These are the different ways how I tried to install and run the app. Success means the app launched fine and showed me my first page. Fail means it crashes after showing the splash screen.

- Debug the app in Windows 10: **success**
- Start a release version from Visual Studio without debugging in Windows 10: **success**
- Debug the app in Windows 8.1: **success**
- Start a release version from Visual Studio without debugging in Windows 8.1: **success**
- Remote debugging from Windows 10 to Windows 8.1: **success**
- Remote debugging from Windows to Windows 8.1, but just start a release version from Visual Studio without debugging: **success**
- Sideload app-packages in Windows 8.1: **success**
- Install from Store on Windows 10: **success**
- Install from Store on Windows 8.1: **fail**

I can reproduce this issue on every Windows 8.1 machine. The app just crashes a few seconds after it showed the splash screen.

I went looking in the event viewer and found an error saying that a remote procedure call failed. There's also an application error saying that *combase.dll* is the faulting module.

After loading the first page, the app checks if your PC has internet access. If it doesn't, it lets you know you need to check your internet connection. The app has the permission to access the internet as client.

I also configured an application-wide exception handler that catches every unhandled exception. The app then just shows an error message.

If you want to try for yourself: https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9wzdncrfj9d5

Comment: I don't see the app in the store. Maybe because you only support dutch

Comment: @magicandre1981 that's probably the reason

Comment: in this case most users here can't help. capture a crash dump (**procdump -ma -i C:\dumps**). zip the dmp from C:\dmps and share the zip (Onedrive). I'll try to look at the dmp with windbg.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Here you are: http://1drv.ms/1NSZXMl Thanks in advance!

Comment: that are minidumps. Have you passed the **-ma** to generate full dumps?

Comment: Those are dumps I found on the machines where the app crashed. Do I have to run that command and then open the app or right after the crash happened?

Comment: run the procdump command on that system. the command generates full dumps. share such full dump

Comment: were you able to generate a full dump on that system?

Comment: were you able to generate a full dump?

Comment: Quite busy with other projects at the moment, I'll let you know when I generated that dump.

Comment: I faced the same issue. Have you found the solution?